# Show div if URL contains Zip codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, arrays, forms

Here's the scenario (in .NET so Jquery is a must):

1. User enters a zip code in the fields below, upon hitting enter/submit on they get redirected to a page with the URL string having the zip code entry tied to it which will then show a div with some information in it and hide others not related to it, all based on the zip code entry.

My Code:

```
<pre>
function goToPage() {
var page = document.getElementById('ZipCode').value;
window.location = "results.aspx?=ZipCode" + page;
}

&lt;input type="text" id="ZipCode"/&gt;
&lt;button type="button" value="submit" id="ZipSearch" 
onclick="goToPage();"&gt;SEARCH&lt;/button&gt;
</pre>
```

2. The results.aspx page will be something like www.website.com/results.aspx?=91343 which will then show the California div, and hide the other divs.

   ```
   <div id="california" style="display:none">
   <p>California</p>
   </div>
   <div id="washington" style="display:none">
   <p>Washington</p>
   </div>

   if (window.location.href.indexOf("91343") > -1) {
   $('#washington').hide();
   $('#nationwide').show();}
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("98001") > -1) {
   $('#washington').show();
   $('#nationwide').hide();}
   ```

I can get it to work with just a single zip code, how do I get it to work with multiple?
Thank you

Comment: how about naming your divs with the zip code and hidding any div that does not match the provided zipcode ?

Comment: What is an example of a url with multiple zipcodes? I.e. is there a separator btwn each code? Have you looked at feeding the url to a basic regex?

Comment: Mauricio, could do that, but there are 43,000 zip codes in the US so that will just weight that page down like crazy.

Comment: uncleoptimus - I've tried this:
if (window.location.href.indexOf("91343","91444","29183") > -1) {
But it just doesn't work.